# Custom derive macro to create getters and setters

Tags: rust, macros

To learn how custom derive macros work in Rust, I decided to create a simple derive macro to provide getters and setters for a given struct.

It would be used like this:

```rust
#[derive(GetSet)]
pub struct Example {
    #[get]
    #[set]
    field1: String,
    #[get]
    field2: i32,
}
```

However, there are some things that feel wrong to me about it:

1. The code uses both `proc_macro` and `proc_macro2`, is this necessary?
2. Currently, every getter / setter is in their own `impl` block. But the `quote!` macro requires code that is well-formed regarding braces, so I think I cannot create `impl #name {` first and fill in the methods afterwards. Is there a better way?
3. The function identifiers are created with `format!`, is this okay?
4. Would it be possible to adapt it so one could just write

```rust
#[get, set]
field: (),
```

instead of

```rust
#[get]
#[set]
field: (),
```

Apart from that, what else would you improve or change?

Here is the code:

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use proc_macro2::{Ident, Span};
use quote::quote;
use syn::{Data, DeriveInput};

#[proc_macro_derive(GetSet, attributes(get, set))]
pub fn get_set_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let ast: DeriveInput = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    let mut gen = proc_macro2::TokenStream::new();

    let name = &ast.ident;
    let data = &ast.data;

    if let Data::Struct(data_struct) = data {
        let fields = &data_struct.fields;

        for field in fields {
            let field_name = field
                .ident
                .as_ref()
                .expect("struct idents are required for this to work!");
            let field_type = &field.ty;

            for attr in &field.attrs {
                let path = attr.path();

                if path.is_ident("get") {
                    let fn_ident = Ident::new(&format!("get_{field_name}"), Span::call_site());

                    let getter = quote! {
                        impl #name {
                            pub fn #fn_ident(&self) -> &#field_type {
                                &self.#field_name
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    gen.extend(getter);
                }
                if path.is_ident("set") {
                    let fn_ident = Ident::new(&format!("set_{field_name}"), Span::call_site());

                    let setter = quote! {
                        impl #name {
                            pub fn #fn_ident(&mut self, new: #field_type) {
                                self.#field_name = new;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    gen.extend(setter);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        panic!("no support for enums or unions!")
    }

    gen.into()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The code uses both `proc_macro` and `proc_macro2`, is this necessary?

This is normal. `proc_macro` is the compiler API stub, **only available to proc-macro crates**, and `proc_macro2` is a plain library that doesn't depend on the compiler proc macro API. It's *possible* to write a proc-macro crate that doesn't depend on `proc_macro2` at all, but then you'd also need to avoid using `syn` and `quote`, or any other proc-macro utility libraries — they all depend on `proc_macro2`, precisely because without it there's no way to manipulate tokens in library code (as opposed to proc-macro crate code).

> Currently, every getter / setter is in their own impl block. But the quote! macro requires code that is well-formed regarding braces, so I think I cannot create `impl #name {` first and fill in the methods afterwards.

You can use an iterator or collection in `quote!` to assemble the complete structure at once.

```rust
let mut functions: Vec<proc_macro2::TokenStream> = Vec::new();

// ... gather functions into vector ...

// this is the entire output of the derive (no `gen` stream)
quote! {
    impl #name {
        #( #functions )*
    }
}
```

> The function identifiers are created with `format!`, is this okay?

Yes.

> Would it be possible to adapt it …

No, [the syntax of attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) does not allow `#[foo, bar]`. You have to pick one name for the attribute, but it can have parameters: `#[getset(get, set)]`.

> Apart from that, what else would you improve or change?

It looks pretty good. You asked the right questions and I can't think of more things to change.